# Enabling Wireless gave me Blue Screen of Death

Tags: wireless-networking, bsod

I cant seem to get wireless working anymore. When I go into the Device Manager and right-click on "Intel(R) Pro/Wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter" and enable it, I get an instant BSOD.

I've tried it twice with the same result. I'm running Windows XP SP3. I've verified that the driver is the latest version. Also I do not have any question marks in the device manager.

Comment: Did it only recently stop working?

Comment: Which operating system? What laptop model? What operating system original came on the laptop? Is the wireless internal or does it plug in via USB, PCIMCIA, etc?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is Windows XP... running on Fujitsu Siemens Lifebook E model. The wireless is internal and XP came originally with the laptop.

Does that give you any clues of what is going on? :)

Answer (score 2):

download the latest drivers for it, uninstall it from the device manager.  scan for new hardware and when it asks for the driver, use the updated one.  see if this works.

Comment: that didnt work im afraid. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the device was not made to run on WinXP but on Windows 7. Try it on a machine with Win7 installed and see if you get the same BSOD

Comment: What do you mean? It is installed for Win XP, I know it as I checked the installation files.